# Getting the document ID of a ListTile item

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the document ID of a ListTile from Firebase in Flutter when that Tile is tapped:

```
Stream collectionStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('items').snapshots();
Stream documentStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('items').doc('ABC123').snapshots();

class AllItemList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AllItemListState createState() => _AllItemListState();
}

class _AllItemListState extends State<AllItemList> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _itemStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('items').snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _itemStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return ListView(
          //physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data['title']),
              subtitle: Text(data['userName']),
              trailing: Text('Priority: '+data['priority'].toString()),
              onTap: (){
                print('This Document ID');
              },
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I checked out this post:
[Flutter - How can i query the same document id - on the next page - as a ListTile that was previously clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62838687/flutter-how-can-i-query-the-same-document-id-on-the-next-page-as-a-listtil)

but I'm still stuck

Comment: You can save that docid as a field when placing the document, this way you can get the id from the saved document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My implementation might be a little too different from yours, but I use:

`document.reference.id`

Example:

```
_dataSource.snapshots().listen((event) {
  final List<Thing> documents = event.docs.map((document) => document
    .data()
    .rebuild((doc) => doc..firebaseDocumentId = document.reference.id)).toList();
    // doing my biz logic here

});
```

Ignore the `.rebuild` that's just part of the `built_value` lib I am using